# Find and replace string in between characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find a string in a file and reformat it.

String to find format:

```
[title](link)
```

example:

```
[template application](https://stackoverflow.com/sample/base-app)
```

I would like to change that to HTML link:

```
<a href="link">title</a>
```

example:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/sample/base-app">template application</a>
```

What is the best way to do it?
I am thinking regular expressions but I have no clue to how achieve that. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  could take advantage of the fact that the [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function receives another function as a parameter for replacement:

```
import re

line = '[template application](https://stackoverflow.com/sample/base-app)'


def repl(match):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(match.group(2), match.group(1))


result = re.sub('\[(.+?)\]\((https?.+?)\)', repl, line)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/sample/base-app">template application</a>
```

The pattern `'\[(.+?)\]\((https?.+?)\)'` captures everything between brackets followed by something link like (starts with http), notice that you must escape brackets and parenthesis because they have a special meaning inside a regex.

Or as suggested by @JonClements, you could use:

```
re.sub('\[(.+?)\]\((https?.+?)\)', r'<a href="\2">\1</a>', line)
```

instead of the `repl` function.

Comment: Any particular reason to go the route of a substitution function instead of a string instead: `re.sub('\[(.+?)\]\((https?.+?)\)', r'<a href="\2">\1</a>', line)
` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your desired result using `re` as Daniel said, But if you dont want to use regex, you can do this with `str.split`:

```
line = '[template application](https://stackoverflow.com/sample/base-app)'
link = line.split('(')[1][:-1]
title = line.split(']')[0][1:]

result = '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, title)
```

if you are using Python 3.6 or higher:

```
result = f'<a href="{link}">{title}</a>'
```